# How can I pass param from the controller to pre-save middleware?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My function in the controller:

```
 getWeather: (req, res) => {
           const userId = req.params.userId;
           weather.save().then(() => {
                        console.log('weather saved')
                    }).catch(error => { return res.status(500).json({ error }) })
 }
```

The middleware in the model, here I want to get the **userId** as a param

```
weatherSchema.pre('save', function (req, res, next) {

    console.log( req + ' pre!! ');  //req     
    next();
})
```

I don't succeed, I tried to look for similar questions but their answers did not help me. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're confused between express middleware and mongoose middleware. The `save` mongoose middleware that you are using is a document middleware and it only gets a single parameter i.e. `next` and it is triggered before `.save()`.

I guess an express middleware would solve your problem.

```
app.get("/someroute", (req, res, next) => {
    // Here you have access to req.params.userId
    next();
}, (req, res) => {
    // Here you can save it to the db
})
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, according to you it is not possible for the pre- save mongoose middleware to get a parameter through the save function in the controller?

Comment: @sharon Ya, as far as I know